# Are there materials permeable to oxygen and carbon dioxide but not nitrogen?

Tags: diffusion

Are there materials permeable to $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ but not $\ce{N2}$?

Would this even be possible in theory? Can it be done at even at pressures of 300 atm?

Comment: Permeable is not a 0/1 quality. For three unpolar small gas molecules, the difference in permeability for each will never be very much different, but certainly it will be different.